# Pruning unused classes when using the Maven Assembly plugin

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I am using the [Maven Assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) to create several JAR files for one of my projects. I have already been able to configure it so that specific resources of my own are excluded from the final product, to reduce the size of the output files.

The problem is that I am using several third-party libraries, such as [HPPC](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.carrotsearch/hppc) and [FastUtil](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/it.unimi.dsi/fastutil), each of which adds several MiB to the output JAR. Since the JAR file in question will regularly be sent over a slow-ish connection, that kind of size increase is not really workable.

I thought about adding more exclusion directives for the assembly plugin, but that would probably require a rather lengthy trial-and-error process to properly trim things down. It could also become a maintenance nightmare when moving to newer versions of those dependencies.

Since I will only be using a tiny subset of the code from each library, without using reflection, is there a way to *automatically* remove unneeded classes from specific dependencies during the assembly process?

Or, to make the question more clear: If I have a dependency D that contains classes CA and CB, is there a way to *automatically* drop CB when creating the JAR file, if I am only using CA in my project?

Comment: I think that Maven is very specific on that: if you don't need something just exclude it, and if you need "something", let's say, just for compilation, specify it also and that won't be included in your artifact. IntelliJ IDEA has a great "Maven Dependencies" diagram so you can inspect every and each dependency

Comment: @ɐuıɥɔɐɯ: I think that my question may not have been clear enough. I have already removed any unused dependencies... now I'm trying to prune classes from within the remaining dependencies when assembling the output JAR.

Comment: The maven-shade-plugin may be a better fit for slimming down an individual jar if you know up front what classes are (not) needed.  I don't know of any utility that examines the classpath at build time, digging into the jars, to identify what's not being used and stripping it out.

Comment: @user944849: I'm thinking of using something along the lines of ProGuard, but I have yet to figure it out...